# matplotlib auto generates dates in my x-axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I have a DataFrame that consist of 2 columns

```
Transaction Week | Completed 
2021-01-10       | 63 
2021-01-17       | 76
2021-01-24       | 63 
2021-01-31       | 20
```

I cannot understand why after I plot the graph, my x-axis has more than 4 dates (My DataFrame only has 4 entries). How can I remove those dates?

```
x=Weekly_Settled_Trans_Status['Transaction Week']
y=Weekly_Settled_Trans_Status['Completed']
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.tick_params('x', labelrotation=45)
```

[image: Screenshot]